# Are there any specific scenarios to use Liferay search container over Dandelion datatables framework?

Tags: datatables, liferay, dandelion, searchcontainer

Are there any specific scenarios to use Liferay search container over Dandelion data tables framework,when Data tables provide far better collection of features(such as multi column sorting,filtering,searching,i18,etc) and is easy to integrate too.To rephrase my question,should data tables be preferred over search container for all scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 100% your choice. Search Container is styled as every built-in list of entities within Liferay (because Liferay uses Search Container). *If* you use it or choose *any* other method/framework/technology is strictly your choice.

Make your choice based on

- appearance and level of visual integration you'd like to have
- familiarity with the framework
- suitability for the job
- maintainability of the solution for whoever is going to maintain your code
- assumed stability (or level of maintenance) for your solution of choice

If you end up using either one of the proposed solutions or yet another one: So be it. For your future maintainers sake, just make sure to choose *one* and standardize on it.

If you're customizing Liferay's UI, you might still need to *understand* Search Container, but that's a different story.

Comment: ya totally..understanding search container is definitely a must.You never know,who could turn out to be your friend in need.Thanks!